# Apache .htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to rewrite this urls

```
http://www.website.com/game/newscore.php
http://www.website.com/game/index.php?act=Arcade&do=newscore
http://www.website.com/game/index.php?act=Arcade&do=savescore
```

all in one to

```
http://www.website.com/savescore
```

and

```
http://www.website.com/game/index.php?act=Arcade&do=verifyscore
```

in

```
http://www.website.com/game/verifyscore
```

This is my current .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Anyone can help me please?
Thx all.

Comment: is the `//` double slash intended?

Comment: Death: what you mean by impossible?

Comment: First use `@Death` to inform me! second: Assume I typed `http://www.website.com/savescore` in browser's address bar, how your web server knows which rule to apply, you have three rules for one address!

Comment: @Death because all three addresses have the same action and post params...i know it isn't the best practice but to make everything work i need these hack...thx for helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^http://www.website.com/game/newscore.php$ http://www.website.com/savescore [R,L]
RewriteRule ^http://www.website.com/game/index.php?act=Arcade&do=(new|save)score$ http://www.website.com/savescore [R,L]
RewriteRule ^http://www.website.com/game/index.php?act=Arcade&do=verifyscore$ http://www.website.com/game/verifyscore [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```